# Count the number of matching words between two strings

Tags: javascript, jquery, string, match

Hello I would like to ask some help how I can do this in Jquery

Count the number of matching words (in order) between two strings so I can generate accuracy.

```js
// Example
string1 = "The lazy fox jumps over the fence" // (7 words)
string2 = "The lazy dog jumps under a fence yesterday" // (8 words)
```

`Output: 4`

Accuracy is (4 correct words/7 words to check) = 57%

Any idea will be appreciated

Comment: Must the words also be in the same position to be counted as accurate?

Comment: Hi Terry, not exactly but they need to be in order. for example if we have two "the" words in string2. The first "the" and the second "the" will be counted as 2 correct words.

Comment: `string3 = "The fence is for a fox who jumps"`. - How many matches does this have with string1 and string2?

Comment: @aven, if compared to string1 then its has 3 correct matches (The, fox, jumps)

Comment: @ARGO but you said it should be in the same order

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could `split` each string to words and match the same words by using `filter`

```js
function getWords(str) {
  return str.split(" ").filter(Boolean);
}

function getMatchedWords(words1, words2) {
  return words1.filter((word) => words2.includes(word));
}

const string1 = "The lazy fox jumps over the fence";
const string2 = "The lazy dog jumps under a fence yesterday";

const words1 = getWords(string1);
const words2 = getWords(string2);

const matchedWords = getMatchedWords(words1, words2);

const ratio = +((100 * matchedWords.length) / words1.length).toPrecision(2);

console.log(ratio);
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sets from strings containing `word, position` tuples then intersect them via logical conjuction `&`. Depending on whether or not it should be case sensitive apply `toUpperCase` operation before. The result set contains matching words from all strings.

By this way you can test any number of strings for the extinct they match to each other.

I’m on mobile, writing code is not the case, sorry.